# How to correctly format strings to populate labels in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, formatting, label

I have an app which have a segue paying data to an UIView and I need to display the percent sign after the number and also only one or two decimal digits. I’m doing as you can see below because I could not do the same from the first example below using “format:” into the second example.

```
    var dailyUviString: String {
        return String(format: "%.1f", dailyUvi!)
    }
    var dailyPopString: String {
        return String("\(dailyPop!*100) %")
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Use a NumberFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to include the percentage sign in your format you just need to add it twice:

```
var dailyPopString: String {
    String(format: "%.1f%%", dailyPop!*100)   // "50.0%"
}
```

Another option is to use `NumberFormatter`. Note that when using `NumberFormatter` with `numberStyle` set to `.percent` you don't need to multiply your value by 100:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .percent
numberFormatter.string(for: dailyPop!)  // "50.0%"
```

Comment: Perfect! So simple. 